# VMWare Centos copy past not work

Tags: vmware, centos, copy-paste

colleagues.

I have a problem with copy-past from host (Windows XP) and guest (Centos) OS.
I have installed **VMWare Tools** but it didn't help me.
Strange situation... before I installed a VMWare tools I was able to copy from Windows XP and paste to Centos GUI (but not in console).
Once I have installed **VMWare Tools** It stops working.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using Centos 6.2 as a guest OS on Windows 7, and I can copy-paste from host and guest.  The version of VMWare tools is an updated version. I don't face any issue with it.  Earlier, the host OS was WinXP, even there, I didn't faced any such issue.  I think, vmware tools are not correctly installed or need an upgrade.  Try upgrading vmware tools to the latest version and see if it fixes the issue.